# how can i solve this bundle install error

Tags: ruby, jekyll, eventmachine

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler
cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 228, which depends on
    jekyll-avatar was resolved to 0.7.0, which depends on
      jekyll was resolved to 3.9.3, which depends on
        em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
          eventmachine
```

I'm trying to run a website locally, but when I run `bundle install` I get this error.

Comment: It looks like you copy'n'pasted only a part of the error message. The actual error message is missing. Please share the full message.

Comment: Does this project have a Gemfile.lock file?